# From $P_n$ be the proposition that $n!- 3^n >0$ to $P_{n+1}$

Tags: inequality, induction

> Quoting: Let $P_n$ be the proposition that $n!- 3^n >0$.
>
> If $P_n$ is true, then so is $P_{n+1}$
> $$(n+1)!- 3^{n+1} = n!(n+1) -3^{n+1}> 3^n(n+1)-3^{n+1}$$ (by the induction assumption)

I am not quite understanding the end result.

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you see why, if we can show $3^n(n+1)-3^{n+1}>0$, we're done? Oh, and you need to establish a base case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming that $P_n$ is true. And $P_n$ says that $n! > 3^n$. So you have $n!(n+1) > 3^n (n+1)$, by *assumption*. Hence you have $$n!(n+1) - 3^{n+1} > 3^n(n+1) - 3^{n+1} = n \cdot 3^n - 2\cdot 3^{n} = 3^n (n-2)$$

Now since you are only interested in $n \geqslant 7$ can you see why the above must be positive?